# Automatic updates on laravel app

Tags: laravel, updates

Is there a way to have wordpress like update system in my laravel app?
I want to be able to provide my users with the ability to click a button and the app will automatically override all changed files and all database seeders and migrations will run.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by updates and *all changed files*? What the reason you need to run migrations? They are developed for setting up your app on deploy/after your push some new code in.

Comment: Well, maybe I have explained wrong. Let's imagine the following scenario: User has v. 1.0 of my app installed. I release a new version and the user gets a notification in the admin panel. The user clicks a button and the app is automatically updated to version 1.1. The things is, there might be changes to database with the update (since the app is still in beta and I keep on adding features that depend on the creation of new columns in database..)